# Halfing an "array" until only individuals are left

Tags: list-manipulation

I have created an "array" of sorts using

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[vector], i++,
  codes[i] = {}
  ];
```

The vector is a vector of probabilities, the sum of the vector is 1. I want to start halfing the vector and after each halfing, I want to add a number to the appropriate `codes[i]` variable. Meaning I half the vector, then I half the halves, etc. etc., until only individuals are left, and that is where the program ends, with each `codes[i]` filled with appropriate numbers.
The halfing is done based on the sums of probabilities, not the length of the vector, so a 6 item vector 
could be halfed into 2 and 4 items.

I have tried looping the halfing, but of course, it cuts it, assigns numbers, and then starts halfing the first half, and ignores the second, from where it progresses, and only a small part of the vector is done correctly in the end.

```
total = 1;
sum = 0;
For[i = 1, sum < (total/2), i++,    
  sum = sum + vector[[i]];
  cut = i;
  ];
```

To cut a vector in half I run a cycle, summing the probabilities in the vector until the sum is greater or equal to half of what I need. The value of total is 1, because the sum of all the probabilities is 1, therefore I run a cycle adding up until the sum is greater than 0.5, then I save the index of the last number, and I run more cycles that fill the codes[i] vectors with numbers. I fill them with 0s and 1s, so I fill codes[i] with 0s up until the cut variable, then I fill the rest with 1s.

Is it possible to make such a loop, where it completes the entire vector?

Comment: Perhaps an example illustrating how "halving" a vector of probabilities is done will be helpful.

Comment: ` total = 1;
sum = 0;
For[i = 1, sum < (total/2), i++,    
  sum = sum + vector[[i]];
  cut = i;
  ]; 
`
I run a cycle, summing the probabilities in the vector until the sum is greater or equal to half of what I need. 
The value of total is 1, because the sum of all the probabilities is 1, therefore I run a cycle adding up until the sum is greater than 0.5, then I save the index of the last number, and I run more cycles that fill the `codes[i]` vectors with numbers. I fill them with 0s and 1s, so I fill `codes[i]` with 0s up until the `cut` variable, then I fill the rest with 1s.

Comment: Please include this information in [your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/220147/edit), instead of the comments.

Comment: can you illustrate the steps using `vector = {.2, .1, .4, .3}`?

Comment: in the first step you find `cut=3`  and split `vector` into two pieces `vector2 ={{0.2, 0.1, 0.4}, {0.3}}`... then what?

Comment: The vector would be arranged in descending order. so 'vector = {.4, .3, .2, .1}'. Then I cut it, and assign numbers to codes[] variables, 0s up to cut, 1s after cut, and then repeat the halving.
The final values of codes[] then will be
codes[1]={00}
codes[2]={01}
codes[3]={10}
codes[4]={11}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[splitF, codeF]

splitF = ReplaceRepeated[lst : {_?NumericQ, __?NumericQ} :> 
    TakeDrop[lst, 1 + LengthWhile[Accumulate[Normalize[lst, Total]], # < .5 &]]];

codeF = Position[splitF@#, {_?NumericQ}] - 1 &;
```

`splitF` splits an input list repeatedly until all sublists are singletons. A non-singleton list is first normalized (so that its sum is 1) and accumulated and then split when accumulated total exceeds the threshold `.5`.

`codeF` uses the position indices as the code for each singleton sublist.

***Examples:***

```
vec1 = {.4, .3, .2, .1};
vec2 = {.3, .3, .2, .1, .1};
vec3 = {.3, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1};
SeedRandom[777]
vec4 = ReverseSort@Normalize[RandomReal[1, 8], Total];

Grid[Prepend[Column /@ {#, splitF@#, codeF@#} & /@ {vec1, vec2, vec3,  vec4}, 
  {"vec", "splitF@vec", "codeF@vec"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

We can pad the codes on the left (by repeating the left-most digit) or right (by repeating the right-most digit) to get equal-length codes:

```
ClearAll[padLeft, padRight, codeFL, codeFR]

padLeft = PadLeft[#, Automatic, \[FormalX]] /. 
    l : {Longest[\[FormalX] ..], a_, b___} :> (l /. \[FormalX] -> a) &;

padRight = PadRight[#, Automatic, \[FormalX]] /. 
    l : {b___, a_, Longest[\[FormalX] ..]} :> (l /. \[FormalX] -> a) &;

codeFL = padLeft[Position[splitF@#, {_?NumericQ}] - 1] &;

codeFR = padRight[Position[splitF@#, {_?NumericQ}] - 1] &;
Grid[Prepend[Column/@ {#, splitF @ #,  codeF @ #, codeFL @ #, codeFR @ #} & /@ 
     {vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4},
   {"vec", "splitF@vec", "codeF@vec", "codeFL@vec", "codeFR@vec"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[777]
vec5 = ReverseSort@Normalize[RandomReal[1, 30], Total];

Row[ArrayPlot[ToExpression[#] @ vec5, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16], 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 20, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[{Range @ Length @ vec5, 
         Row /@ ToExpression[#] @ vec5}], None}, 
       {All, All}}] & /@ 
    {"codeF", "codeFL", "codeFR"}, 
  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the first block of code? From 'Clear All' to 'codeFR'.

Comment: @Drobdien,  added a few notes. Hope this helps.